# How do I use newer pip after the upgrade? (10 --> 18)

Tags: python, pip, pycharm

I'm using Python 3.6 on Pycharm `venv` (virtual environment provided by IDE)

Terminal kept telling me to upgrade my `pip` from old 10.0.1 to newer 18:

> You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 18.0 is available
>
> You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

So I upgraded my pip with the suggested command.

However, when I check my `pip` version by `pip --version`, it's still on 10.0.1 and `pip` keeps telling me to upgrade.

> pip 10.0.1 from
>   h:\pycharmprojects\my_project\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-10.0.1-py3.6.egg\pip
>   (python 3.6)

I'm sure it's already up-to-date by checking IDE's interpreter settings. 
[image: Settings > Python Interpreter]

I know it doesn't really matter but it bothers me pretty much.

I already tried closing and opening new terminal but that clearly doesn't work.

How do I use my newly installed `pip`? Is it just Pycharm's problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using a virtual environment in pycharm, you update the version of pip inside that virtual environment.

If you want to upgrade pip outside of the venv, type

```
python -m pip install pip -U
```

Where *python* is how you start python from the terminal,
which may be *python3* or *py -3.6* depending on your operating system.

To install inside the virtual environment, you can activate
that inside the terminal and then type the above command.

Answer (score 0):

If you run this command in your PyCharm terminal, it will resolve the warning about pip:

```
python -m pip install -U --force-reinstall pip
```

Here are some comments on the [JetBrains community page](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000530279-unable-to-upgrade-the-pip-version-?page=1#community_comment_360000167760)